# HttpClient with BaseAddress

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dotnet-httpclient, webhttpbinding

I have a problem calling a [webHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) WCF end point using [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [BaseAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.baseaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

**HttpClient**

I created a [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance specifying the [BaseAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.baseaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property as a local host endpoint.

[image]

**GetAsync Call**

I then call the [GetAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158912%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method passing in the additional Uri inforamtion.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("/Layouts/{0}", machineInformation.LocalMachineName()));
```

[image]

**Service endpoint**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Layouts/{machineAssetName}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<LayoutsDto> GetLayouts(string machineAssetName);
```

**Problem**

The problem I am having is that the is that `/AndonService.svc` part of the BaseAddress is being truncated so the resultant call goes to `https://localhost:44302/Layouts/1100-00277` rather that `https://localhost:44302/AndonService.svc/Layouts/1100-00277` resulting in a 404 Not Found.

Is there a reason the BaseAddress is being truncated in the GetAsync call? How do I get around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is HttpClient BaseAddress not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438416/why-is-httpclient-baseaddress-not-working)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In the `BaseAddress`, just include the final slash: `https://localhost:44302/AndonService.svc/`. If you don't, the final part of the path is discarded, because it's not considered to be a "directory".

This sample code illustrates the difference:

```
// No final slash
var baseUri = new Uri("https://localhost:44302/AndonService.svc");
var uri = new Uri(baseUri, "Layouts/1100-00277");
Console.WriteLine(uri);
// Prints "https://localhost:44302/Layouts/1100-00277"


// With final slash
var baseUri = new Uri("https://localhost:44302/AndonService.svc/");
var uri = new Uri(baseUri, "Layouts/1100-00277");
Console.WriteLine(uri);
// Prints "https://localhost:44302/AndonService.svc/Layouts/1100-00277"
```

Comment: Please see my question and answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438416/why-is-httpclient-baseaddress-not-working This answer leaves off an important detail.