# What is "base address" in httpclient.baseaddress?

Tags: vb.net

According to this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.baseaddress(v=vs.118).aspx

It contains the base address. Well, duh....

I do not know if microsoft documentation is meant to be understood. What the hell is base address?

Is it the URL with only hostname?

Like `StackOverflow.com`?

Is it the whole URL like `stackoverflow.com/question/ask`

Is it the whole URL including the parameter, such as `stackoverflow.com/hello/world?dfdsdf=34fgdsg`

What is base address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`httpclient.baseaddress` is used as the starting point to send your http requests.

**Example**

If you have to send many requests starting with the same address

```
https://stackoverflow.com/hello/moreinfo1/1
https://stackoverflow.com/hello/moreinfo2/2
```

So you have to set

```
clt.baseaddress = New Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/hello/")
Dim response1 As HttpResponseMessage = Await clt.GetAsync("moreinfo1/1")
Dim response2 As HttpResponseMessage = Await clt.GetAsync("moreinfo2/2")
```

Else *(if not set baseaddress property)* you have to write the full URI every time you are sending a request

```
Dim response1 As HttpResponseMessage = Await clt.GetAsync("https://stackoverflow.com/hello/moreinfo1/1")
Dim response2 As HttpResponseMessage = Await clt.GetAsync("https://stackoverflow.com/hello/moreinfo2/2")
```

**Useful Links**

- [Why is HttpClient BaseAddress not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438416/why-is-httpclient-baseaddress-not-working)
- [HttpClient with BaseAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609118/httpclient-with-baseaddress)
- https://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient-vbnet

Comment: The second way seems simpler.