# Azure Cognitive service (Face detection API) returns resource not found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I have created a separate resource for face detection cognitive service api and it gives the endpoint as follows,

```
https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0
```

so while making request like below,

```
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileContents);
byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
var response = await _client.PostAsync("detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,smile,facialHair,glasses,headPose,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise", byteContent);
var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

it throws an error saying,

> Resource Not Found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to add trailing slash to end of your base URI otherwise the `v1.0` will be discarded as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20609275/7034621).

So:

```
var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = "https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/" };
```