# Asana API 403 Response in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, oauth, httprequest, asana-api

I am trying to implement a Xamarin app that works with the Asana API.

I have successfully implemented the OAuth as documented in the Asana documentation [here](https://developers.asana.com/docs/authentication-basics)... at least I assume it is successful. I get an access token from the token endpoint in an HTTPResponse with HTTP Status "OK".

But then when I turn around and try to make an API call with that same access token, I get a 403 Forbidden error. I tried the same API call in my browser (after logging in to Asana), and it works fine, which leads me to believe that I do have access to the resource, I must have an issue with authorizing the request on my end.

The API call in question is ([documented here](https://developers.asana.com/docs/get-multiple-workspaces)): https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces.

My C# code is as follows (abbreviated to relevant parts, and assume that `ACCESS_TOKEN` contains the access token I got from the token exchange endpoint):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ACCESS_TOKEN);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
```

And then I use this `HttpClient` (named `client`) in the following function:

```
// Returns a list of the Asana workspace names for the logged in user.
private async Task<List<string>> GetWorkspacesAsync()
{
    List<string> namesList = new List<string>();

    // Send the HTTP Request and get a response.
    this.UpdateToken(); // Refreshes the token if needed using the refresh token.
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/workspaces"))
    {
        // Handle a bad (not ok) response.
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //  !!!THIS KEEPS TRIGGERING WITH response.StatusCode AS 403 Forbidden!!!

            // Set up a stream reader to read the response.
            // This is for TESTING ONLY
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
            {
                // Extract the json object from the response.
                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.WriteLine(content);
            }

            throw new HttpRequestException("Bad HTTP Response was returned.");
        }

        // If execution reaches this point, the Http Response returned with code OK.

        // Set up a stream reader to read the response.
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
        {
            // Extract the json object from the response.
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            JsonValue responseJson = JsonValue.Parse(content);

            foreach (JsonValue workspaceJson in responseJson["data"])
            {
                string workspaceName = workspaceJson["name"];
                Debug.WriteLine("Workspace Name: " + workspaceName);

                namesList.Add(workspaceName);
            }
        }
    }

    // I have other awaited interactions with app storage in here, hence the need for the function to be async.

    return namesList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer. It looks like I was using `HttpClient` incorrectly; a subtle thing that should be equivalent, but is not due to the way it is implemented.

**The answer**

I needed to place the final slash at the end of the `BaseAddress` property of `HttpClient`, and NOT at the start of the relative address for the specific request. [This answered question explains this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609118/httpclient-with-baseaddress).

**To fix my code**

I needed to change the setting up of the `BaseAddress`:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/"; // FINAL SLASH NEEDED HERE
```

And remove the slash from the request's relative address:

```
// DO NOT put slash before relative address "workspaces" here
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("workspaces"))
```

**Why I got the original error**

When `HttpClient` combined the `BaseAddress` with the relative URI I specified in `GetAsync()`, it dropped off some of the base address, since the final slash was not included. The resulting address from combining the `BaseAddress` with the relative URI was a valid URL, but not a valid page/API call in Asana. Asana thus did an automatic redirect to a login page, which, of course, the rest of the API call would be forbidden from there.

**How I discovered this**

In debugging, I grabbed the access token returned during my app's authorization with Asana. I then recreated the request to the "/workspaces" API myself in [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), and the request worked as expected. This confirmed that my authorization worked fine, and the issue must be with the specific request rather than the authorization. In debugging I then looked into the `HttpResponseMessage`, which has a property called `RequestMessage`, that includes the actual URL the `GetAsync()` made the request against. I observed the Login URL from Asana, rather than the `BaseAddress` I specified... which led me to the question/
answer linked above.

Hope this explanation helps anyone who comes across a similar error!