# Unable to call web api via httpclient

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have a controller with the following route:

```
[HttpGet("/{id}/studentrank")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetStudentRank(Guid id){
...
}
```

Note, the decorator over the class is: [Route("api/[controller]")]

so it should be called by: api/student/{guid here}/studentrank

This works fine in swagger. However when I call it as follow, I get an internal server error and does not even break in the controller:

```
var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync($"/api/student/{id}/studentrank");
```

Any idea of what could be missing?

Comment: Attach a debugger and read the server output. Or enable dev exceptions and see the description directly. And a couple of things are missing in the question: We don't know whether this action is in StudentController, you say so only; we also don't know what type `id` is, it might not be a guid.

Comment: Have you set a BaseAddress on the HttpClient?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609118/httpclient-with-baseaddress

Comment: What is the body of the response.

Answer (score 0):

The HttpGet does not contain the route parameter. Assuming the method is in the StudentController class you should do it like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetStudentRank/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetStudentRank(Guid id){
...
}

var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync($"{BaseUrl}/Student/GetStudentRank/{id}");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, cause it is a `Guid` and not a `string` the type must be declared in the route and or the route must not start with a slash if it should be combined with the route on the class:

```
[HttpGet("{id:guid}/studentrank")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetStudentRank(Guid id){
...
}
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know that one.