Integration test using test containers in .NET 6 and xunit stuck at test
I am trying to run a xunit test using test containers for a dotnet 6 API project. The container instance is running and I can test the endpoint in the browser and get the response but the xunit project stuck at the first test with no action!! Depicted in the below pictures added


    public class IntegrationTestWebAppFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
 {
     private readonly IContainer _apiContainer;
     public HttpClient Client { get; private set; }

     public IntegrationTestWebAppFactory()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("initiating the factory");
         _apiContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
                                   .WithImage("***.azurecr.io/weather.api:v1")
                                    .WithEnvironment("DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL", "***")
                                    .WithEnvironment("DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME", "***")
                                    .WithEnvironment("DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD", "***")
                                    .WithPortBinding(8080, 80)
                                     .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilHttpRequestIsSucceeded(r => r.ForPort(8080)))
                                    .Build();
     }

     public async Task InitializeAsync()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("InitializeAsync");
         await _apiContainer.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

         Client = new HttpClient
         {
             BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/")
         };
         Console.WriteLine("InitializeAsync done");
     }

     async Task IAsyncLifetime.DisposeAsync()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("DisposeAsync");
         await _apiContainer.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
     }
 }


 public class UnitTest1 : IClassFixture<IntegrationTestWebAppFactory>
 {
     private readonly IntegrationTestWebAppFactory _factory;
     public UnitTest1(IntegrationTestWebAppFactory factory)
     {
         _factory = factory;
     }

     [Fact]
     public async Task Should_Return_Forcast()
     {
         //   Arrange
         if(_factory is null)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("factory is null");
             return;
         }
         var client = _factory.Client;
         //   Act
         var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:8080/WeatherForecast");
         response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
         var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         Assert.NotEmpty(responseString);
     }
 }


What happens if instead of "localhost" during HttpClient creation you'll use apiContainer.GetHost() method?

there is no .GetHost() method.

Sry. I meant on a container instance.

I am talking about the container instance too. There is no GetHost() method

Oh mu, I just now see that you provided base address in initialization and passed full url in the test itself, what happens if you invoke GetAsync just with WeatherForecast endpoint url?

Regarding http client and base address https://stackoverflow.com/a/20609275/6482931

The method ForPort(ushort) receives the container port, not the host port. Please try ForPort(80) instead. Additionally, please follow our Best Practices; your configuration may not work on every Docker runtime.
